# Выделяется ли запятыми словосочетание "по согласовании"?

Tags: пунктуация

Добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, требуется ли запятая в предложении: "По согласовании (,) Вам сообщу".
Благодарю!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По согласовании = после согласования. Это обычное обстоятельство, не деепричастный оборот, запятой нет, как и в следующих примерах с ПО = ПОСЛЕ: по окончании школы он поступил...; по истечении времени всё закончилось и т. д.

У Лопатина в [примере](http://orthographic.academic.ru/54825/%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%) к правилу правописания тоже запятой нет.

Answer (score -1):

Если "по согласовании" имеет значение "согласовав", то запятая ставится.

Comment: Ни в коем разе.

Согласовав, я пошёл домой.
По согласовании я пошёл домой.